# How to populate DropDown List in Asp.net using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I need to populate my dropdownList in asp.net - I am using this method in my web service

```
public List<object[]> GetList()
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var List_ = (from p in pls.plsList() select new {pls.Id , pls.Name}).ToList();
    List.Add(new object[]
    {
        List_
    });
    return List;
}
```

I have this function to call this method

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/p_test.asmx/GetList",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/Json; Charset= Utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        var optionhtml1 = '<option value="' + 0 + '">' 
            + "New" + '</option>';
        $(".cs3").append(optionhtml1);

        $.each(data, function (i) {

            var optionhtml = '<option value="' +
                data[i].Value + '">' + data[i].Text + '</option>';
            $(".cs3").append(optionhtml);
        });
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

This my SelectList

```
<select id="cs3" name="cs3" class="cs3 form-control form-control-sm"></select>
```

My problem is My List not Binding some help thank you :)

Comment: you need add before db.Configuration; List<object[]> List = new List<object[]>(); and List = List_

Comment: Yes i do in top after methode

Comment: if you are sure that ajax call works fine and the response contains the data, try to change the for each in this way:
$.each(data,function(key, value)
                {
                    $(".cs3").append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
                });

Answer (score 0):

You can use method like this,

```
public JsonResult GetList()
    {
       List<object[]> List = new List<object[]>();
       db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
       var List_ = (from p in pls.plsList() select new {pls.Id , pls.Name}).ToList();
       List = List_ 
       
       return Json(List,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and check console.log(data)

Comment: Thank You Bro i am getting data with my methode, problem is select list don't Bind??